# Printing fibonacci number in TASM assembly

Tags: assembly, numbers, fibonacci, tasm

In university we started learning TASM assembly language. The point is, I need help because I'm completely lost on my assignment. I need to scan a number from keyboard and print fibonacci's n-number. Example: you type in 6, program prints out 8.

Here's my unfinished code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data 
    number db 255

.code
start:
    mov dx, @data
    mov ds, dx
    mov al, 0
    mov bl, 1

.readline:
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset number
    mov cx, dx;
    int 21h

.fibonacci:
    add al, bl
    mov dl, al
    mov al, bl
    mov bl, dl

    loop .fibonacci
    int 21h
.writeln
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, dl
    int 21h


end start
```

After this, I just don't know what should I do or if there are any mistakes made. Could anyone give me advice what I need to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://ututi.com/subject/vu/mif/kompiuteriu-architektura/file/11899/get) is a PDF manual with some code examples needed to implement user input and output.

Below is a snippet of untested code to give you an idea of how to calculate a Fibonacci sequence without recursion.

```
    mov  cx, 6
    mov  ax, 0    ;a = 0
    mov  bx, 1    ;b = 1
fib:
    mov  dx, ax 
    add  dx, bx   ;sum = a + b
    mov  ax, bx   ;a = b
    mov  bx, dx   ;b = sum
    loop fib
```

Take note that you will have to set the Count register (CX) to the given user input.

Also keep in mind that you are using 32 bit registers, so the biggest Fibonacci number you will be able to store in the register is 46th.

Comment: The actual calculation of Fibonacci is obviously not what the OP is having trouble with.

Comment: That is true. I have attended the same lecture OP is and have struggled with the same tasks. The PDF file I provided has all the necessary code examples to construct the final solution (it is not in English). I do not have access to TASM emulators right now so I cannot fix and test his code.

Comment: Thank you debes.is for your fast answer. I'll take a look at pdf. Hope it will help me completing my first program.

Comment: The Link is broken.

Answer (score -2):

```
.MODEL SMALL

.DATA
.CODE
 MAIN PROC

            MOV AX,@DATA
            MOV DX,AX

            MOV AL,20
            MOV CL,10
            MOV AH,00
            DIV CL
            MOV DX,AX
            ADD DX,3030h
            MOV AH,02H
            INT 21H

            MOV DL,DH
            INT 21H




            MOV AX,4C00H
            INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: This appears to be code for printing a 2-digit integer.  There are questions on SO that could be answered with this code (plus some text explaining how / why it works, and so on!) but this question isn't on of them.